# calling a javascript function inside .js file vs html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having some trouble calling a javascript function inside of the html page. When I move the function inside the linked/external file it works fine. Can anyone help with this?

Here is my external file.js

```
function request_token(session) {
    $.ajax({
        url: api_url, 
        data: {api_id: api_id},
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp : "callback",
        success: function(data) {
            var token = data.token;
            alert(token)
        }
    }); 
};
```

And here is just the simple call to the function that I want to load once the document is ready...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    request_token('1234');
});
</script>
```

When I move request_token('1234'); into the file external file, it works fine

Comment: Can you post how/where you're including the JS in the HTML file? What errors does the console show?

Comment: What is the question? If it works fine, what's the problem? You should avoid including script directly in your HTML anyway, so it's probably better that this error is forcing you to use external .js files.

Comment: I need to call the function inside the page b/c I am using a dynamic variable that changes based on the page/php. The external files and page script are located in the head of the document..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jQuery's `getScript()` function.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getScript('external.js');
        request_token('1234');
    });
</script>
```

**[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)**